# iCloud Sync does work on iPhone & Mac but not on iPad

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have found a strange problem with iCloud Sync.

**Situation:** I have developed an iOS, iPadOS & macOS App using SwiftUI. All three Versions share the same Codebase *(macOS Version is a Catalyst iPad Version)*. The Project does support iCloud Sync via the `NSPersistenceCloudKitContainer` to sync data between all 3 devices.

**Problem:** iCloud Sync works perfectly between my iPhone and my Mac, but when using it with my iPad, I face a really strange problem. When creating a new CoreData Object on my iPad, it will appear on my other devices after a few Seconds, which is totally fine. However, when creating the CoreData Object on my iPhone or Mac, it will not appear on the iPad *(I waited 10min)*. Only when closing and reopening the App, the Object will appear.

**Details:** I not even have to fully exit the App. It is enough to just swipe up to Application Picker and select the App again.

**Question:** Does anyone has an idea or something what could cause this strange error? And remember: All three devices are using the same codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your have enabled Push and remote notifications per the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit)

```
Project Settings > Signing and Capabilities
```

[Sync CoreData with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/syncing_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit) using

```
try? persistentContainer.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
```

Comment: is this suppose to be try before loadPersistentStores or after?

Comment: I put it after. so the context is ready.